# How to pre-cache image for Facebook with Social Forward?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

when using Marketing Cloud (ExactTarget) Social forward is it possible to pre-cache the image to be associated with the post? I've tried adding a met og:image tag to the Social Slot, but it didn't seem to affect the post.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<!-- RegionStart[ socialslot:"Shared content region 1",
title:"First shared email content",
description:"This is an example of shared content",
csskey:"portfolio css 1"] -->

<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.exampleimageurl.com/goeshere.png" />

<a href="%%=GetSocialPublishURLByName('Facebook', 'US', 'Shared content region 1')=%%" alias="Social Forward to Facebook" title="Publish to Facebook"> <img src="http://image.exct.net/lib/ffcf14/m/1/social_default_facebook_icon.jpg" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook" border="0"> </a>

<!-- RegionEnd[ socialslot:"Shared content region 1"] -->
```

Any ideas? Thanks, Kevin